# Conditional Select

Tags: sql-server

My table has 4 columns `(name, A, B, C)`.

I need to build a query that has the following logic:

```
Select name,
    a as value1,
    b or c as value2
from table
```

Logic:

```
A <> ''
If B <> '' 
    then value2 = b else 
    if c <> '' then value2 = c 
        else value2 = ''
```

Comment: Try looking at using [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you meant by `A <> ''`; but here is an example that should give you the right idea at least.

```
USE [tempdb] ;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
(
    [name] VARCHAR(15) NULL
  , [A]    VARCHAR(15) NULL
  , [B]    VARCHAR(15) NULL
  , [C]    VARCHAR(15) NULL  
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl] VALUES ('name1','A1','','');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl] VALUES ('name2','A2','','C2');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl] VALUES ('name3','','B3','C3');
GO

SELECT
    [name]
  , [A] AS value1
  , CASE WHEN [B] <> '' THEN [B]
         WHEN [C] <> '' THEN [C]
         ELSE ''
    END AS value2
FROM
    [dbo].[tbl];
GO

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl];
GO
```